# Snowflake duplicates

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a major issue with duplicates in Snowflake.
Data flow:

1. From SAP I'm loading data to PSA layer (no duplicates here)
2. Calling procedures to load data to RAW layer (duplicates here)
3. Calling procedures to Business layer (duplicates here)

All of the procedures from 2,3 are loading in pararell.

Do you have idea how not have duplicates in Snowflake? Or how to delete one of the duplicates ex. I have two or more same rows I want only one row in my tables

Comment: the useual solution is to not put the duplicate in. But this fundamentally happens if you check/insert in parallel, not that you really should be inserting into the same table from different "threads" as the later will be stalled, and yet the time of the stall will be double charged. Anyways, ether you need to use something like a outside synchronization, to avoid  concurrency, or push into a stream, and only pull/de-dup/merge in one thread.

Comment: Can you please explain where the duplicates are coming from?

Comment: @Marcel I don't know exacly. I'm using talend jobs and two talend jobs are calling at the same time procedures in Snowflake\

Comment: @wilkux Are you able to execute only one of the Talend jobs? Do the Talend jobs execute the same procedure? 
Instead of running the Talend jobs, you could try running a scheduled task that executes the procedure at specified times of the day to ensure it is only executed once per day for example, and not executed (therefore inserting) in parallel.